# "excess elements in scalar initializer" when using igraph C library to generate a network with power law degree distribution

Tags: c++, c, igraph

I'm using igraph C library and I want to generate a undirected, without loop, and a single edge network with power law degree distribution. The parameters I have are:

- number of nodes = 25,000
- number of edges = 25,000
- alpha = 2.16104

I want to use the `igraph_static_power_law_game` graph generator and I wrote the following code.

```
#include <igraph.h>

int main() {

  igraph_t g;
  int igraph_static_power_law_game(&g, 25000, 25000, 2.16104, -1, 0, 0, 1);
  igraph_destroy(&g);

  return 0;
}
```

I use the the following command to compile the code.

```
gcc testpw.cpp -I/usr/local/Cellar/igraph/0.7.1/include/igraph -L/usr/local/Cellar/igraph/0.7.1/lib -ligraph -o testpw
```

And the following error appeared.

```
error: excess elements in scalar initializer
  int igraph_static_power_law_game(&g, 25000, 25000, 2.16104, -1, 0, 0, 1);
      ^                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Since I can't find an example of using igraph C library to generate power-law degree network online, I don't know what's the way to make it. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

If you're compiling C code, you don't need the `int` before `igraph_static_power_law_game()`, because that makes the line look like a faulty declaration of the function instead of an invocation of the function.

Or, if you're compiling C++ code, the compiler is interpreting the contents of the parentheses as an initializer for the variable `igraph_static_power_law_game` and complaining that a single `int` variable does not need multiple initializers.

Either way, writing:

```
igraph_static_power_law_game(&g, 25000, 25000, 2.16104, -1, 0, 0, 1);
```

fixes the immediate compilation error.  You should probably be using something like:

```
if (igraph_static_power_law_game(&g, 25000, 25000, 2.16104, -1, 0, 0, 1) != 0)
    …report error…
```

so that if the function fails, you know about it.

Comment: Jonathan, thank you so much, this is exactly what I missed. And thank you for your suggestion of testing the setting too! I really appreciate your response!